# How can i make rectangles filled with specific percentage of blue using css or bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an image on my laptop to what i exactly mean, but i don't know how to show to you.
Briefly, i want to make a rectangle filled with specific percentage of color blue, so can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a value for your blue and you can make a rectangle in css, you can change the lightness, saturation, and opacity percentages with `hsla(colour, saturation, lightness, opacity)`.

To get the "percentages" that I think you want, you would have to change the saturation percentage. For example, to have a fully saturated blue 240, you could do `hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 1)`. For 50% blue, you would do `hsla(240, 50%, 50%, 1)`, and for 25% blue you could do `hsla(240, 25%, 50%, 1)`, and so on.

To better understand how hsla works and to find what you mean by "percentage" of blue, look at the hsla colour picker here:

http://hslpicker.com/#00f

Then simply apply the desired variable to your rectangle.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If this answer worked, could you please accept it by pressing the green tick :) if it is missing something, please comment?

Comment: unfortunately i'm just a new member here and i don't have a permission to do that,
i have only population of 13 :(

Comment: If you have more than 1 reputation, you should see a green tick just below the upvote button to mark the answer as "accepted". This gives you 2 reputation, and it gives me 15. It would be a great way of showing your appreciation for a good/relevant answer! (it was invented to stop people clogging up comments with "thank you" and "good answer")

Comment: thank you for your explanation, the idea is clear now and i accepted your answer

Comment: Thanks for accepting! One last tip for stack overflow: never comment "thank you". Instead of making the person feel happy, they may get annoyed as such comments used to clog up the comments section. The best thank you you can give is an acceptance and upvote!